# How would you sort by multiple attributes if and only if that attribute exists?

Tags: python, function, sorting, lambda

Say you want to sort a list of lists by multiple attributes:

```
arr = [['a', 10, 72], ['s', 12, 31], ['g', 5, 1], ['a', 10, 1]]
```

Normally I would sort the list by:

```
sorted(arr, key = lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1]), int(x[2]))
```

However, how would I sort this list is the elements within the list were different lengths and some of them were shorter than 3 elements:

```
arr = [['a', 10, 72], ['s', 12, 31], ['g', 5, 1], ['a', 10, 1], ['s', 10], ['s', 12, 31, 44]]
```

Is there a way to check within a lambda function if an element exists?
So:

1. sort by x[1]
2. sort by x[2] if len(x) > 1
3. sort by x[3] if len(x) > 2

Comment: are there only 3 elements in the sublist?

Comment: Why do you not just write a normal function and pass it as `key` instead of cramming everything in a `lambda`?

Comment: Yeah that’s what I was confused about, I wasn’t sure how to do that, the element to element comparison

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
arr = [['a', 10, 72], ['s', 12, 31], ['g', 5, 1], ['a', 10, 1], ['s', 10], ['s', 12, 31, 44]]
arrrsorted= sorted(arr,key=lambda x: x[2] if len(x)>2 else(x[1] if len(x)>1 else x[0]) )
arrrsorted
```

Output:

```
[['g', 5, 1], ['a', 10, 1], ['s', 10], ['s', 12, 31], ['s', 12, 31, 44], ['a', 10, 72]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide a complete function instead of a lambda.

```
def my_key(input):
    # ...
    return ...

sorted(arr, key=my_key)
```